# support of tor-sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose $D$ is an effective smooth irreducible divisor on a smooth variety $X$.
suppose $W$ is a closed subvariety of $X$ not contained in $D$.
Suppose $L$ is a line bundle on $X$ and consider the exact sequence:
$$
0\rightarrow L\otimes O(-D) \rightarrow L \rightarrow i_*(L_{|D})\rightarrow 0.
$$
Here $i:D\hookrightarrow X$.
Now restrict this exact sequence on $W$ to get the exact sequence:
$$
Tor^1(i_*(L_{|D}), O_W)\rightarrow L\otimes O(-D)\otimes O_W\rightarrow L\otimes O_W \rightarrow i_*(L_{|D}) \otimes O_W \rightarrow 0.
$$ 
What is the support of the sheaves $Tor^1$ and of $i_*(L_D)\otimes O_W$.

Can we assume that outside a codimension two subset of $W$, these two sheaves are zero ?

Answer (score 2):

The support of the tensor product is the intersection of supports, i.e. $D \cap W$. The support of $Tor^1$ is the union of those irreducible components of $W$ (including embedded components) which are contained in $D$.